# Как проверить существует ли куки?

Tags: php, cookie

Как проверить существует ли куки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Также как и обычную переменную:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['myCookie']))   
{   
    echo "Oh my God, переменная is gone ))";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```